# How can I run a curl command for each line of output from my Perl script?

Tags: unix, command-line, find

I have a perl script that writes out an array filled with integers to stdout, each on a separate line.  So I would get output like:

```
412
917
1
etc
```

What I would like to do is be able to pipe the output of this script into xargs, and make a curl call using each integer.  Something like this:

```
cat input.json | ./jsonValueExtracter.pl -s exampleId | xargs curl http://brsitv01:8080/exampleId/$1 > example$1.json
```

Below is an excerpt of a simple script I am using.

```
my @values;
while(<STDIN>) {
     chomp;
     s/\s+//g; # Remove spaces
     s/"//g; # Remove single quotes
     push @values, /$opt_s:(\w+),?/g;
}

print join(" \n",@values);
```

However, this doesn't work the way I would expect.  When I run the following command:

```
cat input.json | perl jsonValueExtracter.pl -s exampleId | xargs echo http://brsitv01:8080/exampleId/$1
```

I get the output:

```
http://brsitv01:8080/exampleId/ 412 917 1
```

Is there anything special I need to do to use the output of a perl script in xargs?

Thanks

Comment: note: useless use of `cat`:  `perl jsonValueExtracter.pl -s exampleId < input.json | xargs ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xargs doesn't use $1 like that. $1 is blank, and xargs just puts the numbers at the end of the command line.

You probably want to use a bash for loop like:

```
for i in `./jsonValueExtracter.pl -s exampleId < input.json`
do
  curl http://brsitv01:8080/exampleId/$i > example$i.json
done
```

Which can be written on one line with semi-colons:

```
for i in `./jsonValueExtracter.pl -s exampleId < input.json`; do curl http://brsitv01:8080/exampleId/$i > example$i.json; done
```

Note that you don't need cat:

```
cat [file] | script.foo
```

Is equivalent to:

```
script.foo < [file]
```

Answer (score 5):

Add -n 1 to xargs to make it eat only one argument on each run.